# How to replace substring in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a lot of mongodb documents in a collection of the form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d02d179a2d0dead77a4c9c5"),
    "distributed" : false,
    "winner" : false,
    "number" : "855254",
    "dateCreated" : "13-06-2019 19:43:05",
    "date" : ""
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d02d179a2d0dead77a4c9c7"),
    "distributed" : false,
    "winner" : false,
    "number" : "263141",
    "dateCreated" : "13-06-2019 19:43:05",
    "date" : ""
}
```

I want to replace all the data in the `"number"` field for:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d02d179a2d0dead77a4c9c5"),
    "distributed" : false,
    "winner" : false,
    "number" : "8-55254",
    "dateCreated" : "13-06-2019 19:43:05",
    "date" : ""
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d02d179a2d0dead77a4c9c7"),
    "distributed" : false,
    "winner" : false,
    "number" : "2-63141",
    "dateCreated" : "13-06-2019 19:43:05",
    "date" : ""
}
```

I've tried it in some ways but no success.

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, you can take advantage of the fact that [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) now accepts an aggregation pipeline, which allows updating a field based on its current value:

```
// { number: "855254" }
db.collection.update(
  {},
  [{ $set: {
    number: { $concat: [
      { $substr: [ "$number", 0, 1 ] },
      "-",
      { $substr: [ "$number", 1, -1 ] }
    ]}
  }}],
  { multi: true }
)
// { number: "8-55254" }
```

- The first part `{}` is the match query, filtering which documents to update (in this case all documents). If you want to be safe, you can filter on documents whose `number` value size is larger than 1.
- The second part `[{ $set: { number: { $concat: [ ... }]` is the update aggregation pipeline:

  - Note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline.
  - [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) (alias of `$addFields`) is a new aggregation operator which in this case replaces the field's value.
  - [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) is used twice: once to get the first character and another time to get the tail of the string (using `-1` as a third parameter of `$substr` means getting the rest of the string).
  - And `$concat` joins the two parts with `"-"`.
- Don't forget `{ multi: true }`, otherwise only the first matching document will be updated.

Comment: For older versions, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)